# How can I loop this function for a certain amount of times?

Tags: python

```
import sys
g = int(input())
def TwoStackSum():
    sumList = []
    for a0 in range(g):
            n,m,x = input().strip().split(' ')
            n,m,x = [int(n),int(m),int(x)]
            a = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
            b = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
            while sum(sumList) < x:
                try:
                    sumList.append(a.pop(a0))
                    sumList.append(b.pop(a0))
                except IndexError:
                    break
    while sum(sumList) > x:
        sumList.pop(len(sumList)-1)
    print(len(sumList))
    sumList.clear()
    TwoStackSum()

TwoStackSum()
```

I want to run the TwoStackSum function the same amount of times as the range in the for loop, but it runs without any limit.

Comment: Is your intent to call the function recursively or to have it called from a caller N times?

Comment: I want to call the function g times

Comment: you're calling `TwoStackSum()` inconditionnally from inside it! no wonder why it runs forever.

Comment: If you want to call the `TwoStackSum` function `g` times, why are you using `for` with `range(g)` inside of the function and why are you making the another call to `TwoStackSum` from within the function? I think you should be moving these two out of the function block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call your method `g` times, do this:

```
for _ in range(g):
    TwoStackSum()
```

But remove the `TwoStackSum()` call from inside the function (after `sumList.clear()` ), otherwise it will loop forever. Currently when you call your method, it calls itself, from where it calls itself again, indefinitely.

You will get a `RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'` if you run it like it currently is.

However make sure this is what you want, because the for loop inside the function:

```
for a0 in range(g):
```

will also be called `g` times, for each call of the `TwoStackSum()` function.